# Unable to launch the applications

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jnlp

Hi, I have a java swing application, I want to start it via `jnlp`, I configured my project web start configuration but when I push the launch button doesn't work. Do you know why?

Here is the error

```
Java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LoginPage\dist"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verifyCodebase(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.AppPolicy.grantUnrestrictedAccess(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: we can't answer this question with just the provided information. Give us some code and context.

Comment: i dont have any parseInt or String, i just have a form wich netbeans created automatically, i am just testing how can i start my swing local with jnlp, i set my web start, i have launch.jnlp and launch.html in dist folder, i cant run it why?

Comment: It's a long time ago, but can you remember what you did eventually?

Answer (score 1):

With just this error we can only tell you that your problem is happening because of a `parseInt` on a `String` that is not an `int`. 
To correct this you have two possibilities :

1. add `try{}catch(NumberFormatException e){//show error}`
2. Assert that you have the proper things into `parseInt` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
Netbeans 8.01, JDK 1.8u20, JRE project,

Run option:

- 'run as webstart' enabled.

Application/Webstart options:

- Created Certificates Keystore *(Tip: i used 'portecle' )*
- Codebase: Local execution (by which the preview shows: 'file:/C:/..../')

The JNLP which is created by the project says;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="file:/C:/<snip>/dist/" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>netbeans_prj</title>
        <vendor>bla</vendor>
        <homepage href=""/>
        <description>netbeans_prj</description>
        <description kind="short">netbeans_prj</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
</information>
    <update check="background"/>
    <security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
    <resources>
        <j2se java-vm-args="-Xmx512m -Xverify:none" version="1.7+"/>
        <jar href="netbeans_prj.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="lib/all_ext.jar"/>
</resources>
    <application-desc main-class="<snip>">
    <argument>-h</argument>
<argument>127.0.0.1</argument>
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```