# .Jar file runs in netbeans but not when opened outside

Tags: java, swing, exception, netbeans, java-web-start

I have looked at:
[why doesn't my jar file run outside netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811589/why-doesnt-my-jar-file-run-outside-netbeans)
and believe I am getting the same problem. The program runs fine in netbeans but doesnt appear when run on the outside. If i go into my task manager I can see that the program is being run. I had my program set up as a java web start app, but then i changed back to a .jar, because no website had big enough space to host it. I believe this may be the root cause of the problem. That, and when i reassigned my resources to be contained in the jar file. When I look at the code output nothing seems wrong. I also debugged it and nothing was wrong. Any help? If you want me to run in the command prompt, could you please say how to do that? Thanks,

Running through webstart it gets to the verifying file stage and then prompts:
Note:"\Users\Camtronius\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SonomaRoller\dist" im pretty sure is the path taken from my JNLP file to launch the webstart.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "\Users\Camtronius\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SonomaRoller\dist"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verifyCodebase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.AppPolicy.grantUnrestrictedAccess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What does `java -jar yourjar` (in a command prompt) output?

Comment: @RC I have updated this. Is this what you were asking for? Could it be that my filepaths are wrong in my JNLP file?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783903/unable-to-launch-the-applications

Comment: can you post your jnlp content? The message makes me think you have `\Users\Camtronius\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SonomaRoller\dist` where java expects a number somewhere in your jnlp

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).