# Converting java application to java applet

Tags: java, applet

I've created a simple java application in eclipse and made a runnable jar of it. The application writes and reads files on my hard disk and there are some http requests running. 
I was wondering if it is possible to make a java applet (never done that before) out of the code I wrote. Sorry if this is a very stupid question, but I couldn't find much about java applets on the web only that they have no main methode and they should have a start/stop and destroy methode. What I'm also worried about is the fact that the application writes to files and I don't know if that is allowed for an applet.

Hope somebody can clear things up a bit.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why deploy an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).  For deploying Java desktop apps. (e.g. based on a `JFrame`), the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  The user just needs to click a link and follow the prompts..

Comment: that's what I'm trying to do, but I get random errors :(

Comment: *"but I get random errors"* Just because you cannot see a pattern in them, doesn't make them random.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as him: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828881/jar-file-runs-in-netbeans-but-not-when-opened-outside, Yesterday I found another simular problem on stackoverflow without solution. I'm getting crazy :p

Comment: Did you check the JNLP using JaNeLA?

Comment: Yes I did check launch.jnlp with JaNeLA. the launch file is located in: C:\Users\teddy\Desktop\host . I got two errors with janela but don't know how to fix them: here is a screenshot http://postimg.org/image/5zr2cqc5r/ (quality is low :s)

Comment: JaNeLA provides a text based report, so copy/paste that instead.  But start a new thread just on that, and I might weigh in (I am the author of JaNeLA).

Comment: wow nice didn't knew that :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can make an applet out of it. You need to develop a custom GUI with Swing/AWT, but extend an Applet class. Next, write you HTML page with embedded tags (browse info here):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html

deploy. 
In order to create an applet, you can use your existing code with minimum changes.

As for the controlling files from your applet, it is definitely possible, but beware security issues. You will need to read some tutorial on those.

Comment: thank you, but I don't really understand how to make that custom GUI (I'm currently using a Jframe with some Textareas etc). And what should I extend with the Applet class?

Comment: Might this be a solution for me?: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html - it works just like JFrame.

Comment: Java Web Start is a little different from Applets. But Web Start is currently recommended instead of applets.

Comment: Will try to get it working with Web Start. Thanks for the help :D